# Apollo local state doesn't return data on ssr

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm implementing a universal react application using Apollo Client, I'm facing an issue where I cannot get the proper initial state value from local state on server-side but it works on client. What I need is to get the proper **themeMode** on both server and client.

Here's what I have on my **serverRenderer**:

```
  const client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> = new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: true,
    link: createHttpLink({
      uri: process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      fetch,
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({ fragmentMatcher }),
    ssrForceFetchDelay: 100,
    ...apolloConfigs,
  });

  const Application = sheets.collect(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Provider store={res.locals.store}>
        <Router location={req.url} context={routerContext}>
          <HelmetProvider context={helmetContext}>
            <App />
          </HelmetProvider>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );

  const cookies = new Cookies(req.headers.cookie);

  const DOMGenerator = (content: string): string => {
    const materialCSS = sheets.toString();
    const state = res.locals.store.getState();
    initialState.themeMode = cookies.get('themeMode');
    client.writeData({ data: initialState });
    const initialApolloState = client.extract();
    const doctype = '<!doctype html>';
    return (
      doctype +
      renderToStaticMarkup(
        <Html
          css={[res.locals.assetPath('bundle.css'), res.locals.assetPath('vendor.css')]}
          helmetContext={helmetContext}
          scripts={[res.locals.assetPath('bundle.js'), res.locals.assetPath('vendor.js')]}
          materialCSS={materialCSS.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '')}
          state={JSON.stringify(state)}
          initialApolloState={JSON.stringify(initialApolloState)}
        >
          {content}
        </Html>
      )
    );
  };

  try {
    const result = await renderToStringWithData(Application);
    return res.send(DOMGenerator(result));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e); // eslint-disable-line
    return res.send('500 Internal Server Error');
  }
```

My **App.tsx**:

```
const QUERY = gql`
  query MyTheme {
    themeMode @client
  }
`;

const App: React.FC<OwnProps> = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(QUERY);
  const theme = Theme(data?.themeMode);
  const styles = Styles({ theme });

  return (
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme} key={data?.themeMode}>
        <Helmet>
          <title>Example</title>
        </Helmet>
        <Global styles={styles.global} />
        <div>Example</div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
};
```

If I log **data** on **App.tsx** it returns **undefined** on server but it returns the correct value on the browser.

Comment: If your local state is in the local storage of the browser, how do you want to get this in SSR? you have to leverage this state to the server first so you can get it

Comment: @ZEE How can I leverage the state on server?